# Error 402 when running partition script in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, database-partitioning

Here is the script which is generated by SQL Server 2014 Management Studio:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [fc_DispatchingHistory](smalldatetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (N'2015-12-31T00:00:00')

    CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [scm_DispatchingHistory] AS PARTITION [fc_DispatchingHistory] TO ([Earlier_than_2016_FileGroup], [PRIMARY])

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching_Audit] DROP CONSTRAINT [FKEY_tbl_Dispatching_Audit_Dispatching_ID_tbl_Dispatching_Dispatching_ID]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Dispatching]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Dispatching] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [Dispatching_ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)


    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_scm_DispatchingHistory_636131462265663820] ON [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching]
    (
        [Pickup_Date]
    )WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [scm_DispatchingHistory]([Pickup_Date])

    DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_scm_DispatchingHistory_636131462265663820] ON [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching_Audit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FKEY_tbl_Dispatching_Audit_Dispatching_ID_tbl_Dispatching_Dispatching_ID] FOREIGN KEY([Dispatching_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching] ([Dispatching_ID])
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching_Audit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FKEY_tbl_Dispatching_Audit_Dispatching_ID_tbl_Dispatching_Dispatching_ID]


    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

It always shows the following error when executed:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tbl_Dispatching, Line 4
>   The data types smalldatetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.

The table has triggers as following:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Delay_Timestamp] ON [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    -- Update Actual_Pickup_Time if "Status_ID" has changed to 5
    UPDATE disp
    SET Actual_Pickup_Time = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM dbo.tbl_Dispatching disp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.Dispatching_ID = disp.Dispatching_ID  -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.Dispatching_ID = disp.Dispatching_ID  -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    WHERE
          i.Status_ID = 5         -- new value is 5 
          AND d.Status_ID <> 5    -- old value was NOT 5

    -- Update Actual_Delivery_Time if "Status_ID" has changed to 8
    UPDATE disp
    SET Actual_Delivery_Time = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM dbo.tbl_Dispatching disp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.Dispatching_ID = disp.Dispatching_ID  -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.Dispatching_ID = disp.Dispatching_ID   -- use PRIMARY KEY of table!
    WHERE
          i.Status_ID = 8         -- new value is 8 
          AND d.Status_ID <> 8    -- old value was NOT 8
```

And a trigger to capture all insert and update actions into another table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FillDispatching_For_Edit_Log]
ON [dbo].[tbl_Dispatching]
AFTER UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO tbl_Dispatching_Log SELECT top 1  'Update' AS Actione_Mod, GETDATE() Action_DateTime, * FROM inserted
```

**MS SQL Server is:**
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
    Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: What is the SQL Server version of the database? Also 2014? And, what Service Pack was installed on the SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (RTM-CU14) (KB3158271) - 12.0.2569.0 (X64) 
 May 27 2016 15:06:08 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Have you installed the latest Service Pack for 2014? That would be Service Pack 2 (cf [SQL Server versions](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.be/)). I just want to rule out problems in SQL Server that were solved in service packs... Looking at the build number, I suspect you have not installed any?

Comment: Upgrading now , will check and comment after the upgrade

Comment: Same issue even after installing service Pack 2

Comment: The error message comes from a Store Procedure. not from this script. Do you have any triggers on those tables, or DDL triggers on the server?

Comment: Yes I do have 3 triggers, I will edit the question for more information about my triggers

Comment: Could you add DDL for `tbl_Dispatching_Audit`?

Comment: @KonstantinTaranov no , I never used DLL